how to add widgets to a list variable and then call out the variable?
I have a row with some dices, I want to change their values based on the simple manipulating the address itself, when I'm having them manually in the children of the row its working all right but when I want to add them as an item to some list then have that list in the children section of the row the code is not working
The working screen:

not working screen after adding widget to the list variable:

import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AskCom extends StatefulWidget {
  const AskCom({super.key});

  @override
  State<AskCom> createState() => _AskComState();
}

class _AskComState extends State<AskCom> {
  int diceV1 = 1;
  int diceV2 = 2;
  int diceV3 = 3;
  List<Widget> diceRow = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(children: diceRow 
//the working part
          //[dice(diceV1),dice(diceV2),dice(diceV3)]
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    diceV1 = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                    diceV2 = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                    diceV3 = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('ROLL')),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                      diceRow.add(dice(diceV1));
                      diceRow.add(dice(diceV2));
                      diceRow.add(dice(diceV3));
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('ADD')),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded dice(diceVal) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/dice/dice$diceVal.png',
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I tired to call the dice as a mthod or class but both had the same result

Check your path for images are correct?
'assets/images/dice/dice1.png', 'assets/images/dice/dice2.png'

i'm not sure but i feel like since you creating your widget inside a list, they a created but they don't depend on the variable.
 diceRow.add(dice(diceV1));
 diceRow.add(dice(diceV2));
 diceRow.add(dice(diceV3));

yeah they are created with 1, 2 and 3. But they don't depend on diceV1 etc...
Maybe you should try create a widget whom takes an int as a variable and then hold a list of dices that will hold the values for your dices.
Something like this
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AskCom extends StatefulWidget {
  const AskCom({super.key});

  @override
  State<AskCom> createState() => _AskComState();
}

class _AskComState extends State<AskCom> {
  int diceV1 = 1;
  int diceV2 = 2;
  int diceV3 = 3;
  List<int> dices = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: dices.map((e) => Dice(variable: e)).toList(),
//the working part
            //[dice(diceV1),dice(diceV2),dice(diceV3)]
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    dices[0] = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                    dices[1] = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                    dices[2] = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('ROLL')),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    dices.add(diceV1);
                    dices.add(diceV2);
                    dices.add(diceV3);
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('ADD')),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dice extends StatelessWidget {
  final int variable;
  const Dice({required this.variable, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        '$variable',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And sorry for the dice widget i made it to just understand your process. Hope it helps.
